# WebGL Water Shader with Texture and Reflection in O3D .. anyone have an example?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, webgl, o3d

WebGL Water Shader with Texture and Reflection in O3D .. anyone have an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's this one: [webgl-water](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/) (http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/)

Or just some waves simulations:
[Linear Waves](http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/waves/wave.html)  (http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/waves/wave.html)